# What should be the better way to implement DES encrypting and decrypting for a string?

Tags: java, android, aes, des

I have gone through theory of [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) and also [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), and it seems better way to use [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). But I didn't find any help on [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), that I can implement in my android application.

So what should be better implementation of [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) in my application. Can you share some links or codes for example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an [example](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings) that implements AES on Android (using the `javax.crypto` package).

Comment: How can I call methods encrypt and decrypt?

Comment: @user594955, What do you mean?

Comment: I am talking about parameters of both method. Can you explain what the mean of raw, clear and raw, encrypted? Actually I can not understand clear of encrypt and raw of decrypt.